# How to start all tests with a clear session after browser crash,

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, python, robotframework, browser-session

Im using WebDriver and Python to automate a website. I have a suite of tests and sometimes running into the following problem.

```
Test no.1 = Login to home page, navigate to Account page, perform some activity, Logout
Test no.2 = Login to home page, navigate to Deposit page, perform some activity, Logout
```

**Problem:** If Test no.1 has a catastrophic failure in Account page, then when Test no.2 kicks off, it logins to the account page instead of the home page.

**Question:** How do I make sure that every test starts with a clean session, i.e. login always goes to the home page?

Clearing the browser cookies and cache doesn't help. I have in my Test Teardown, the Close All Browsers keyword which clears the browser cache and closes the browsers.

Comment: This question has the `robotframework` tag, but this question appears to have nothing to do at all with robotframework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you simply `driver.get(URL)` to your homepage. Not sure why you consider a hack, if that is what you need to recover from test failure.

Comment: Hi Peter, I guess I could force the homepage on the second login. But that would look like a hack.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Could you please repost as a comment and delete your answer?

Comment: Hi Kate, I think thats what I did. I clicked the <Add Comment> button to respond. Sorry this is my first time with StackExchange.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I guess I could simply update the keyword to switch to the home page if login lands elsewhere.